# Error when using empheq in a newcommand

Tags: macros, equations, empheq

I have just started working with the package `empheq` as a way to create a box around equations. I would like to create a pair of short new commands for entering and exiting the empheq environment, but I am running into an error. For reference, here is a minimal example of code that works and that I would like to modify:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}
Y & =Ak^{\alpha}L^{1-\beta}\\
C & =(1-s)Y\\
Y & =C + I + G\\
\Delta K & = I -\delta K
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: minimal working example of boxed equation]

I would like to create the same output but without having to type `\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}` and `\end{empheq}` every time. So I have tried defining two new commands:

```
\newcommand{\eqnboxbegin}{\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}}
\newcommand{\eqnboxend}{\end{empheq}}
```

The first command works as expected, but I have problems with second. That is, this code works:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\eqnboxbegin}{\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}}

\begin{document}

\eqnboxbegin
Y & =Ak^{\alpha}L^{1-\beta}\\
C & =(1-s)Y\\
Y & =C + I + G\\
\Delta K & = I -\delta K
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

But this code produces an error:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\eqnboxbegin}{\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}}
\newcommand{\eqnboxend}{\end{empheq}}

\begin{document}

\eqnboxbegin
Y & =Ak^{\alpha}L^{1-\beta}\\
C & =(1-s)Y\\
Y & =C + I + G\\
\Delta K & = I -\delta K
\eqnboxend

\end{document}
```

The error message reads:

```
paragraph ended before \empheq was complete.
```

I cannot figure this out. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly is the benefit from writing it as macros and not as environments as Troy suggests. Imo environments provide a much more readable code, better separation. Plus with good editors (eg emacs) environments are easy to change. Hints like this becomes quite the hassle in the long run.

Comment: I write a lot documents that require me to go into and out of the same environments frequently. For example, lecture notes contain a lot of itemize and enumerate environments. Instead of typing out begin{itemize} and end{itemize}, I instead only have to type \iz and \zi. True, code is less readable, but the time saving is big and I'm not sharing this code with anyone.

Comment: I would suggest you find yourself a better editor. For example one that can handle user defined templates. In my editor I have a shortcut for a standard preamble, stdpkg after which I just hit Tab, and it expands to the true meaning. Again it makes this a lot more maintainable not just for you, but also to those you later on passes your files on to.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for the tip. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what the `empheq` environment does, (I suspect) they are collect all of the material between `\begin{empheq}` and `\end{empheq}` into a box.
If the delimiter that terminates the box collection is hidden in unexpanded macros, the collection continues until the end of the document.

This new environment works for me:

```
\newenvironment{empheqbox}{%
    \empheq[box=\widefbox]{align}%
}{%
    \endempheq%
}
```

You'll notice that I'm using the direct environment commands for `empheq` because using the environment form also generated the runaway argument error.

---

### Update

After reading the [`empheq` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/empheq.pdf), which references [this document](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/technote.pdf), it is indeed AmS's underlying mechanism for storing the environment's content that is the source of the error.

> This has to do with unfortunately nontrivial technical complications: the given environments must read
>   their contents as a delimited macro argument because they do multipass processing of the contents using algorithms inherited from Spivak’s amstex.tex.
>   The obvious solution—substitution of different algorithms that do box shuffling
>   instead of token shuffling for the multipass calculations—would require rewriting these display environments from the ground up; while that is a worthy goal,
>   it was beyond the original scope of the AmS-LaTeX project.

So it appears that `\begin{}` and `\end{}` are compulsory for robust usage.

The `empheq` author notes this and suggests that my environment above actually be written as

```
\newenvironment{empheqbox}{%
    \setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{align}
    \setkeys{EmphEqOpt}{box=\widefbox}
    \EmphEqMainEnv%
}{%
    \endEmphEqMainEnv%
}
```

Comment: Thanks Troy. I have tried to implement your solution by the problem seems to persist. The environment you defined works well, but when I try to define new commands to get around typing \begin and \end, I get the same issue. But I'm still better off now than when I started. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed.  Please see my more complete answer I have just edited.  It seems you need to use `\begin` and `end`.